# Gráfico do tipo Doughnut Kind com múltiplas séries

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-chart

Estou usando o Angular Charts para plotar um gráfico Doughnut; meu código está estruturado da seguinte forma:

```
$scope.data = [
['abc', 'def'],
['fgh', 'ijk'],
];
$scope.labels = ['Ask', 'Bid'];
$socpe.series = ['Volume Ask', 'Volume Bid'];
$scope.color = ['#66ff33', '#ffff00'];
```

O código acima resulta em algo como a imagem a seguir:

[image: Gráfico com duas cores (uma dentro da outra)]

No entanto, o que preciso é de um gráfico onde as cores sejam mostradas como a seguir:

[image: Gráfico com duas cores (uma ao lado da outra)]

Como podemos ver, o código está atribuindo uma cor por série e o que preciso é de um gráfico com duas cores por série.

Alguém sabe se é possível criar algo assim usando o Angular Charts?

Grato,
Arnaut

Comment: Please translate the question to Portuguese or make a question in [SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Olá Lucas, Traduzido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução está no seguinte código:

```
 $scope.datasetOverride = [{
  fill: true,
  backgroundColor: [
    "#66ff33",
    "#36A2EB",
    "#FFCE56"
  ]
}, {
  fill: true,
  backgroundColor: [
    "#ffff00",
    "#46BFBD",
    "#FDB45C"
  ]
}];
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Krq0cKpN7UAJizsDruju?p=preview)

Respondido em: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41333698/angular-chart-doughnut-kind-with-multiple-series